# .htaccess PHP $_GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this URL Rewrite in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^advertisements /?i=a&p=a [L] 
RewriteRule ^advertisements/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?i=a&p=a&token=$1&change=$2 [L]
```

I want to use the $_GET variable on this page, although it doesn't work as intented.

Currently, when I try to use it like this:

```
http://domain.com/advertisements/07C25EF8EB50E0C2B91F90DB8502AB01E6E01C1D/standard
```

The `$_GET` only contains this:

```
array(2) { ["i"]=> string(1) "a" ["p"]=> string(1) "a" }
```

It doesn't contain the token and the change values. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing an EOL delimiter on your first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^advertisements/?$ /?i=a&p=a [L] 
RewriteRule ^advertisements/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?i=a&p=a&token=$1&change=$2 [L]
```

Comment: +1 but would be better to create one rule that could capture either URL